# Image disappears sometimes

Tags: java

The problem im having is that the first image in images array doesn't get drawn sometimes? Any ideas why? Here is my code in Java: The gui class has the main method. Also ive tried reading in the images in the GUI class and passing the images in the constructor of imagesPanel. In that case nothing at all gets drawn.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ImagePanel extends JPanel implements MouseMotionListener {

    int posX=0;
    int posY=0;

    ArrayList<Image> images = new ArrayList<Image>();
    Image image;

    public ImagePanel() {
        this.addMouseMotionListener(this);

    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        try {
            images.add(ImageIO.read(new File("lion.jpeg")));
            images.add(ImageIO.read(new File("monkey.jpg")));
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
        super.paintComponent(g);
        for(int i=0;i<images.size();i++){
            g.drawImage(images.get(i), posX, posY,100,100, this);
            posX=+120;
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//      posX = arg0.getX();
//      posY = arg0.getY();
//      System.out.println(posX + " " + posY);
//      repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}


    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

    public class GUI {

        public GUI() {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }

        private static void createAndShowGUI() {
            JFrame f = new JFrame("Image Viewer");
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            f.setSize(800, 800);
            f.setVisible(true);

            ImagePanel imagePanel = new ImagePanel();
            f.add(imagePanel);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            new GUI();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't load resources within any paint method, these should be loaded and maintained else where. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Is it a particular imagr that isnt being drawn from your set of pictures?

Comment: MadProgrammer is right  you should actually load and store the images elsewhere, upon calling printComponent you then use those loaded images. With this code it seems you'll constantly loop through your printComponent

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yes i thought of that too. Read the images once in GUI class and then passed it into the constructor of Images Panel. But that didnt work either.

Comment: @redandblue Was any error thrown? If yes post it or tell us what exactly didn't work

Comment: @Juxhin Yes its the lion image that doesnt get drawn sometimes. Maybe gets displayed for a split second

Comment: Any particular reason why lion is .jpeg and not .jpg like monkey?

Comment: @Juxhin No reason, changed both to .jpg. Also when i am reading the images in the Image panel constructor, nothing at all gets drawn. Any idea why is that? Is the paint component method being called before images get loaded?

Comment: Unfortunately I cant see the code well with my phone. Trying printing the stacktrace when catching your Exception e with e.printStackTrace () or something along those linea. If an exception is thrown print the log

Comment: You are always incrementing `posX`, so after a few `paintComponent` calls the images will be way off the screen. Make `posX` and `posY` local variables of the `paintComponent` method.

Comment: Also, please absolutely remove the image loading from `paintComponent`. Not only this is slow and should be done only once, you keep adding images to your list without ever removing them, so on each `paintComponent` call you will add two more images. Soon you will be drawing very many images on every call.